# send a stream chunk by chunk

Tags: c#, process, stream, redirectstandardoutput

Im pretty fresh when it comes to streams in c# but i am somewhat familiar with the basics.

I need help setting up the most efficent way of hooking into a stream of unknown length and send the part read to another function until the end of the stream is reached. Could someone have a look at what i hava and help me fill out the part in the while loop, or maybe if while loop is not the best way tell my what is better. Any help is much appreciated.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "program.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = " -some -arguments"
};
theProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
theProcess.Start();

while (!theProcess.HasExited)
{
    int count = 0;
    var b = new byte[32768]; // 32k
    while ((count = theProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
    {
        SendChunck() // ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how many bytes have been read from the original stream through the `count` variable, so you can just put them into a buffer

```
while ((count = theProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
{
    byte[] actual = b.Take(count).ToArray();
    SendChunck(actual);
}
```

or if your `SendChunk` method is designed to take a `Stream` as parameter you can directly pass it the original object:

```
SendChunck(theProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
```

and then the method can take care of reading the data in chunks.

Comment: Thanks! that made me understand some more!